# Modify an object in a one to many relation using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp

I have a relation one to many between the class Chefprojet and Projet, Chefprojet can handle one or many Projet. I want to modify for a Projet load, its Chefprojet with another Chefprojet, via an input where i specify one of the columns of the new Chefprojet. Here is the code of my JSP.

Chefprojet2ControllerServlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String matricule=request.getParameter("matricule");
        String getHiddenValue=request.getParameter("hidden");
        System.out.println(matricule+" Hidden field Value is :"+getHiddenValue);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);


        try {
            Session session1=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction tx=session1.beginTransaction();
            Query qry1 =  session1.createQuery("select id_chef from Chefprojet where matricule='"+matricule+"' ");
            List list=qry1.list();
            int idm=(int)list.get(0);
            System.out.println(idm);
            Query qry2 =  session1.createQuery("update Projet set id_chef="+idm+""+ "where libelle='"+getHiddenValue+"'");

            tx.commit();

            session1.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

I'm not getting any error in the console, but when i check my sql database, i find nothing modified.
Help me please!

Comment: your questions isn't really very clear

Comment: I want to modify an attribute of the class Projet, this attribute is another class whose name is Chefprojet. There is a one to many relation between ChefProjet and Projet. Chefprojet has many attributes: nom_chef, prenom_chef, matricule. And Projet has also many attributes like: libelle, site, and of course id_chefprojet. I want to modify an the Chefprojet for a Projet load.

Comment: Your question is to broad: generally, you will populate a drop-down with the options. When the user submits the form you  load the ChefProject entity corresponding to the one selected, set it on your Project and then persist the updated project.

Comment: @Alan Hay i edit my question, i hope that i make things more clear now! Have i forget to add something to my code?

Comment: JPA works in terms of objects and entities should not have fields pointing to FKs: they have relationships to objects. Your mappings are incorrect. Neither should you be writing a manual query to load/update fields. You'd be as well using raw JDBC. I'd recommend going to read a JPA tutorial.

Comment: Could you please give me a tutorial of that. I'm new in HIbernate!